# PHP Script won't receive any Data when parsing via JSON despite Http 200 message

Tags: php, json, post, request

this issue is bugging me the entire day now and I have no idea how to fix it. 
I want to simply pass data to a server-side run php script using JSON. Firebug tells me the request comes through, even correctly displaying the payload in the "parameters" section, but my php script won't receive any data.

I've tried var_dump on $_POST and $_REQUEST, both resulting in "Array (0) { }" - Display. Trying to read out the entire raw data stream (file_get_contents('php://input')) produced ' string (0) "" ' as a result.

I've checked my php.ini file, max. upload size is 128M, order of variables is "GPCS", request order is set to "GP". allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include are both set to ON as well.

This is the Notation of the JSON - Object Array I'm trying to get through:

> [{"purchaseDate":"2017-09-09","itemCategory":"Auto","itemPrice":"229.00","itemName":"Tires"},{"purchaseDate":"2017-09-09","itemCategory":"Lebensstil","itemPrice":"30.45","itemName":"Food"}]

It's basically an single JavaScript - Array containing JSON - Objects.

This is my code for the HTML form:

```html
<form name = "add_new_item" method = "post">

    <?php $purchasedate = date("Y-m-d"); ?>

 <input type = "hidden" id = "item_purchase_date" value = "<?php echo $purchasedate; ?>" />

 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo date("d.m.Y");?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Art der Ausgabe</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

   <td><input type = "radio" name = "item_category" value = "Lebensmittel" checked = "checked"/>Lebensmittel</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "item_category" value = "Lebensstil"/>Lebensstil</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "item_category" value = "Auto"/>Auto</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "item_category" value = "Haushalt"/>Haushalt</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "item_category" value = "Musik"/>Musik</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "item_category" value = "Büro"/>Büro</td>
   <td><input type = "radio" name = "item_category" value = "Behoerde"/>Behörde</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

   <td>Rechnungsbetrag: </td>
   <td><input id = "item_price"/></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

   <td>Artikelbezeichnung: </td>
   <td><input id = "item_name" /></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

   <td><p id = "new_item">Weitere Posten</td>
   <td><p id = "close_form">Posten speichern und Ende</td>

  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

This is the JS / Jquery Code to create the object array:

```js
var myObjectArray = []; 
   
 $("#new_item").click (function () {

  var ipd = $("#item_purchase_date").val(); 
  var ict = $("input[name='item_category']:checked").val(); 
  var ipr = $("#item_price").val(); 
  var ina = $("#item_name").val(); 
  
  var $basketItem = $("<div></div>").text(ipd + " | " + ict + " | " + ipr + " € | " + ina); 
  
  $("#basket").append($basketItem); 

 // Objekte erzeugen und in Array schieben 
 
  var newDataObject = { "purchaseDate" : ipd, "itemCategory" : ict, "itemPrice" : ipr, "itemName" : ina }; 

 // console.log(newDataObject); 
  myObjectArray.push(newDataObject); 
  console.log(myObjectArray); 

 $("#add_new_item")[0].reset(); 
 });
```

This is the JSON Snippet; as you can see i use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as content type:

```js
$("#close_form").click (function () {

    $("add_new_item").submit(); 

    var exchangeArray = JSON.stringify(myObjectArray); 
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    
    if (this.readystate == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
     console.log(this.responseText); 
    }
   }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "aserver.php", true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send("objects=" + exchangeArray ); 
  });
```

This would be the server-sided PHP script:

```html
<?php
session_start(); 

echo json_last_error(); 

echo "<br>"; 

var_dump ($_POST["objects"]); 

echo "<br>"; 

print_r($_REQUEST);

echo "<br>"; 
print_r($_POST);

echo "<br>"; 

print_r($_FIL
  ES);
echo "<br>"; 

var_dump($_REQUEST); 

echo "<br>"; 

var_dump($_POST); 

echo "<br>"; 

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo "<br>"; 


var_dump($data); 


?>
```

The request header data:

> Host
>   localhost
>   User-Agent
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
>   Accept
>   */*
>   Accept-Language 
>   de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>   Accept-Encoding 
>   gzip, deflate
>   Referer 
>   http://localhost/ausgaben/eintragneu.php
>   Content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length
>   197
>   Cookie
>   wp-settings-time-1=1498579548;…17792b1639a49e238c33ca199902a
>   Connection
>   keep-alive

The response header data:

> Host
>   localhost
>   User-Agent
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
>   Accept
>   */*
>   Accept-Language 
>   de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
>   Accept-Encoding 
>   gzip, deflate
>   Referer 
>   http://localhost/ausgaben/eintragneu.php
>   Content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length
>   197
>   Cookie
>   wp-settings-time-1=1498579548;…17792b1639a49e238c33ca199902a
>   Connection
>   keep-alive

... and finally the Result shown by the PHP script:

> Blockquote 4    Notice: Undefined index: objects in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ausgaben/aserver.php on line 10         NULL        Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) array(0) { } array(0) { } string(0) ""

I haven't got any idea how to further try and fix this. Any help is appreciated! Thank you guys and gals!

Comment: Have you tried in the click function to replace myObjectArray with some simple JSON?

Comment: Hi Progrock, I tried to pass through a single dummy Object in JSON (see code below); still no change in the outcome at all...

Comment: >var dummyObject = { "purchaseDate" : "10.9.2017", "itemCategory" : "Auto", "itemPrice" : 229, "itemName" : "Reifen" }; 
   
var passData = JSON.stringify (dummyObject); 

[...]

xmlhttp.send("objects=" + passData );

Comment: Make sure you hard refresh your browser.  Your close form click function works for me (minus the add new item code).

Comment: Hi Progrock, I tried to hard refresh several times (I use Firefox) using CTRL - F5, and CTRL-SHIFT-R, and after that wouldn't do the trick, I cleared the Cache manually... Still no improvement. 

So when you ran the snippet, you received the data of the dumm object on a .php page?

Comment: I also created two test pages (Clientside / Serverside) using Code snippets from the W3Schools JSON Documentary... Still nothing. On the client side, everything seems to be ok (correct display of the parameters sent; https status code 200). 
Would it be helpful if I posted the error log containing today's etries?

Comment: Have posted what's working for me below.

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this code here for the OP to test and compare, will remove.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    var_dump($str_json);
    var_dump($_POST);
    die;
}
else {
    // $uri = 'http://localhost' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // //echo $uri;
    // $json = json_encode(['foo' => 'bar', 'bat' => 'man']);
    // $opts = array('http' =>
    //     array(
    //         'method'  => 'POST',
    //         'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    //         'content' => $json
    //     )
    // );

    // $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    // echo file_get_contents($uri, false, $context);
    // die;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>

        <script>
            var myObjectArray = [{'foo':'bar'}];

            window.doFunction = function() {

                var xmlhttp       = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var exchangeArray = JSON.stringify(myObjectArray);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                    {
                        console.log(this.responseText); 
                    }
                };

                xmlhttp.open("POST", "", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send("objects=" + exchangeArray );

            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doFunction();" />
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Note it's `this.readyState` not `this.readystate`, which will help you log the response.

Comment: Thx for the snippet! Unfortunately no improvement; all I can see now using Firebug is a GET-Request from when the page is loaded, but no POST indicated after the button is clicked... Getting really frustrating :(

On the other Hand, PHP sided encoding of the JSON object obviously works...   (the "ELSE"-branch in the PHP script). 

Is there s.th. wrong with my Apache installation?

Comment: Javascript isn't my main language. Missed a semi-colon after the function expression, not sure if that's enough to trip up Firefox.

Comment: I tried a var_dump on the Server request method in the php file; turns out the method is "GET" despite having declared XMLHttprequest as "POST"... Now I'm totally lost.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting confused with the page requests, and javascript ones.  As said, the code above, placed in a file is working for me in Chrome 46 and Firefox Nightly 57.  Split the code into two files and edit where the javascript posts to, if posting to the same script is a distraction..